# run #0 finished with error in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm running with OMNET 5.0 veins 4.4 and SUMO 0.25.0 ...
Everything works fine until the last time when I tried to run my code the simulation window does not appear but its icon exists in the taskbar and the simulation crashes with this error
I have all reinstaller but the problem persists (I have read in other topics that I have to verify the versions but my version is countable according to http://veins.car2x.org/download/)
Can you help me please ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know only OMNeT++ Version 5.0 with INET 3.4 and Versions before ...
In OMNeT++ is Language C++ used, you have to take about nullptr or
garbarge in memory.

The first step is to run GDB in OMNeT++ this graphical user interface
in eclipse editor is quite enough to get neccessary information.

If it don't run after simple checking memory, objects, nullptr, exceptions and so on. See working with valgrind      http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/valgrind/

But usally it is enough to workout with GDB, try to initialize everything, check exception and it works sthhow ...